# snowpark session.create_dataframe failed with pandas dataframe

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I tried to create a snowpark dataframe from pandas df but got error message. Below is my code and error message.

1.snowflake-snowpark-python version 1.8.0

2.pandas version 2.1.1

3.python version 3.10.0

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[("11111P", 1)], columns=["LOCATION_CODE", "LOCATION_KEY"])
print(pd.__version__) #2.1.1
print(isinstance(df, pd.DataFrame)) #this returns True
sf_df = session.create_dataframe(df)
sf_df.write.mode("overwrite").save_as_table("LOCATION")
session.close()
```

error message

```
   1953     raise TypeError("create_dataframe() function does not accept a Row object.")
   1955 if not isinstance(data, (list, tuple)) and (
   1956     not installed_pandas
   1957     or (installed_pandas and not isinstance(data, pandas.DataFrame))
   1958 ):
-> 1959     raise TypeError(
   1960         "create_dataframe() function only accepts data as a list, tuple or a pandas DataFrame."
   1961     )
   1963 # check to see if it is a Pandas DataFrame and if so, write that to a temp
   1964 # table and return as a DataFrame
   1965 if installed_pandas and isinstance(data, pandas.DataFrame):
```

try reinstalling snowflake-snowpark-python in the virtual environment multiple times.

Comment: looks like it only supports pandas version 1.5.3

Comment: Small hint: it is possible to quickly validate package versions using Snowsight - Python Worksheets  https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9R72.png, https://i.stack.imgur.com/6jnFc.png and as separate stored procedure: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mNB4C.png

Comment: @LukaszSzozda great thanks. Btw, did you successfully run this using pandas==2.0.3?

Comment: No, I have not managed to use 2.0.3 version

Answer (score 0):

Snowflake-Snowpark-Python compatibility issue. Need to downgrade snowflake-snowpark-python to 1.9.0 (for Python 3.11, 3.10, 3.9, 3.8) and install snowflake connector using below command,( as per https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/python-connector/python-connector-pandas#installation)

```
pip install snowflake-connector-python[pandas]
```